# How do I know which script names are supported in regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

We have [ISO 15924 Alphabetical Code List](https://unicode.org/iso15924/iso15924-codes.html) and I tried to run the following code:

```
const s = "a人",
    r = /\p{Script=Hans}/u
console.log(s.match(r))
```

But get an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /\p{Script=Hans}/u: Invalid property name
```

So which script names can be used here?

Comment: I don't think it's complaining about the script name. I think it's saying that `Script` isn't a valid property name.

Comment: Script=Han works, without the s, probably not what you were looking for.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html has a list of Unicode scripts. But it says the syntax is `\p{Han}`, I don't see anything like `\p{Script=xxx}`

Comment: @Barmar check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Unicode_character_class_escape

Comment: Search for `# Script (sc)` in https://unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/PropertyValueAliases.txt

Comment: @James Yeah, this is what I'm looking for. Still feel strange about the fact that "Only script names that have an alias can be used in regex character class" (Seems not that reasonable, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

The [**UnicodeMatchProperty**](https://262.ecma-international.org/9.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-unicodematchproperty-p) takes a parameter `p` that is a [List](https://262.ecma-international.org/9.0/#sec-list-and-record-specification-type) of Unicode code points, and the names of the list names can be found in the [***ECMAScript documentation***](https://262.ecma-international.org/) (and via the links provided in that document).

The `name` values for `\p{name}` can be found in [Table 52: Binary Unicode property aliases and their canonical property names](https://262.ecma-international.org/9.0/#table-binary-unicode-properties) and [Table 53: Value aliases and canonical values for the Unicode property General_Category](https://262.ecma-international.org/9.0/#table-unicode-general-category-values)

The `name` values for `Script`/`sc`/`scx` in `\p{Script=name}`/`\p{sc=name}` are available in the [Table 54: Value aliases and canonical values for the Unicode properties Script and Script_Extensions](https://262.ecma-international.org/9.0/#table-unicode-script-values)

Some of these names can also be checked in the https://unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/PropertyValueAliases.txt file. Here are the currently listed values (the tables listed above contain more values for the "General_Category" list):

1. General category (`\p{name}` or `\p{gc=name}`) names:

| p name (e.g. `/\p{L}/u`) | Category full name |
| --- | --- |
| C | Other (includes `Cc`, `Cf`, `Cn`, `Co`, `Cs`) |
| Cc | Control |
| Cf | Format |
| Cn | Unassigned |
| Co | Private_Use |
| Cs | Surrogate |
| L | Letter (includes `Ll`, `Lm`, `Lo`, `Lt`, `Lu`) |
| LC | Cased_Letter (includes `Ll`, `Lt`, `Lu`) |
| Ll | Lowercase_Letter |
| Lm | Modifier_Letter |
| Lo | Other_Letter |
| Lt | Titlecase_Letter |
| Lu | Uppercase_Letter |
| M | Mark |
| Mc | Spacing_Mark |
| Me | Enclosing_Mark |
| Mn | Nonspacing_Mark |
| N | Number (includes `Nd`, `Nl`, `No`) |
| Nd | Decimal_Number |
| Nl | Letter_Number |
| No | Other_Number |
| P | Punctuation (includes `Pc`, `Pd`, `Pe`, `Pf`, `Pi`, `Po`, `Ps`) |
| Pc | Connector_Punctuation |
| Pd | Dash_Punctuation |
| Pe | Close_Punctuation |
| Pf | Final_Punctuation |
| Pi | Initial_Punctuation |
| Po | Other_Punctuation |
| Ps | Open_Punctuation |
| S | Symbol (includes `Sc`, `Sk`, `Sm`, `So`) |
| Sc | Currency_Symbol |
| Sk | Modifier_Symbol |
| Sm | Math_Symbol |
| So | Other_Symbol |
| Z | Separator (includes `Zl`, `Zp`, `Zs`) |
| Zl | Line_Separator |
| Zp | Paragraph_Separator |
| Zs | Space_Separator |

See also [*1.2.5 General Category Property*](https://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#General_Category_Property) at the unicode.org Web site.

2. Script and script extension names:

| p name (e.g. `/\p{sc=Cyrl}/u`) | Script full name |
| --- | --- |
| Adlm | Adlam |
| Aghb | Caucasian_Albanian |
| Ahom | Ahom |
| Arab | Arabic |
| Armi | Imperial_Aramaic |
| Armn | Armenian |
| Avst | Avestan |
| Bali | Balinese |
| Bamu | Bamum |
| Bass | Bassa_Vah |
| Batk | Batak |
| Beng | Bengali |
| Bhks | Bhaiksuki |
| Bopo | Bopomofo |
| Brah | Brahmi |
| Brai | Braille |
| Bugi | Buginese |
| Buhd | Buhid |
| Cakm | Chakma |
| Cans | Canadian_Aboriginal |
| Cari | Carian |
| Cham | Cham |
| Cher | Cherokee |
| Chrs | Chorasmian |
| Copt | Coptic |
| Cpmn | Cypro_Minoan |
| Cprt | Cypriot |
| Cyrl | Cyrillic |
| Deva | Devanagari |
| Diak | Dives_Akuru |
| Dogr | Dogra |
| Dsrt | Deseret |
| Dupl | Duployan |
| Egyp | Egyptian_Hieroglyphs |
| Elba | Elbasan |
| Elym | Elymaic |
| Ethi | Ethiopic |
| Geor | Georgian |
| Glag | Glagolitic |
| Gong | Gunjala_Gondi |
| Gonm | Masaram_Gondi |
| Goth | Gothic |
| Gran | Grantha |
| Grek | Greek |
| Gujr | Gujarati |
| Guru | Gurmukhi |
| Hang | Hangul |
| Hani | Han |
| Hano | Hanunoo |
| Hatr | Hatran |
| Hebr | Hebrew |
| Hira | Hiragana |
| Hluw | Anatolian_Hieroglyphs |
| Hmng | Pahawh_Hmong |
| Hmnp | Nyiakeng_Puachue_Hmong |
| Hrkt | Katakana_Or_Hiragana |
| Hung | Old_Hungarian |
| Ital | Old_Italic |
| Java | Javanese |
| Kali | Kayah_Li |
| Kana | Katakana |
| Kawi | Kawi |
| Khar | Kharoshthi |
| Khmr | Khmer |
| Khoj | Khojki |
| Kits | Khitan_Small_Script |
| Knda | Kannada |
| Kthi | Kaithi |
| Lana | Tai_Tham |
| Laoo | Lao |
| Latn | Latin |
| Lepc | Lepcha |
| Limb | Limbu |
| Lina | Linear_A |
| Linb | Linear_B |
| Lisu | Lisu |
| Lyci | Lycian |
| Lydi | Lydian |
| Mahj | Mahajani |
| Maka | Makasar |
| Mand | Mandaic |
| Mani | Manichaean |
| Marc | Marchen |
| Medf | Medefaidrin |
| Mend | Mende_Kikakui |
| Merc | Meroitic_Cursive |
| Mero | Meroitic_Hieroglyphs |
| Mlym | Malayalam |
| Modi | Modi |
| Mong | Mongolian |
| Mroo | Mro |
| Mtei | Meetei_Mayek |
| Mult | Multani |
| Mymr | Myanmar |
| Nagm | Nag_Mundari |
| Nand | Nandinagari |
| Narb | Old_North_Arabian |
| Nbat | Nabataean |
| Newa | Newa |
| Nkoo | Nko |
| Nshu | Nushu |
| Ogam | Ogham |
| Olck | Ol_Chiki |
| Orkh | Old_Turkic |
| Orya | Oriya |
| Osge | Osage |
| Osma | Osmanya |
| Ougr | Old_Uyghur |
| Palm | Palmyrene |
| Pauc | Pau_Cin_Hau |
| Perm | Old_Permic |
| Phag | Phags_Pa |
| Phli | Inscriptional_Pahlavi |
| Phlp | Psalter_Pahlavi |
| Phnx | Phoenician |
| Plrd | Miao |
| Prti | Inscriptional_Parthian |
| Rjng | Rejang |
| Rohg | Hanifi_Rohingya |
| Runr | Runic |
| Samr | Samaritan |
| Sarb | Old_South_Arabian |
| Saur | Saurashtra |
| Sgnw | SignWriting |
| Shaw | Shavian |
| Shrd | Sharada |
| Sidd | Siddham |
| Sind | Khudawadi |
| Sinh | Sinhala |
| Sogd | Sogdian |
| Sogo | Old_Sogdian |
| Sora | Sora_Sompeng |
| Soyo | Soyombo |
| Sund | Sundanese |
| Sylo | Syloti_Nagri |
| Syrc | Syriac |
| Tagb | Tagbanwa |
| Takr | Takri |
| Tale | Tai_Le |
| Talu | New_Tai_Lue |
| Taml | Tamil |
| Tang | Tangut |
| Tavt | Tai_Viet |
| Telu | Telugu |
| Tfng | Tifinagh |
| Tglg | Tagalog |
| Thaa | Thaana |
| Thai | Thai |
| Tibt | Tibetan |
| Tirh | Tirhuta |
| Tnsa | Tangsa |
| Toto | Toto |
| Ugar | Ugaritic |
| Vaii | Vai |
| Vith | Vithkuqi |
| Wara | Warang_Citi |
| Wcho | Wancho |
| Xpeo | Old_Persian |
| Xsux | Cuneiform |
| Yezi | Yezidi |
| Yiii | Yi |
| Zanb | Zanabazar_Square |
| Zinh | Inherited |
| Zyyy | Common |
| Zzzz | Unknown |

See also [*2 The Script Property*](https://unicode.org/reports/tr24/#Script) and [*3 The Script_Extensions Property*](https://unicode.org/reports/tr24/#Script_Extensions) at the unicode.org Web site.

Comment: So only script names that have an alias can be used in regex character class, right? Seems that Javascript's implementation doesn't completely follow the ISO [15924 Alphabetical Code List](https://unicode.org/iso15924/iso15924-codes.html). For example, the code `Hans` which has no alias.